# Converging Integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

Is this integral convergent or divergent?

$$ \int_1^{\infty}  \sqrt{x}\, \ln\!\left(1+ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\,\text {d}x$$

and

$$ \int_1^{\infty}  \sqrt{x}\, \ln\!\left(1+ \frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right)\,\text {d}x$$

You cannot use the convergence tests because the $\ln$ changes sign ($-$ to $+$ each time) and I couldn't do L'Hospital on the absolute value.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $X=0$, we have

$$\ln(1+X)=X-\frac{X^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(X))$$
with
$$\lim_{X\to 0}\epsilon(X)=0$$

So, with $$X=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
we have
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}X=0$$
because
$$|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}|\le \frac 1x$$

Thus
$$\ln(1+\frac{\sin(x)}{x})=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2x^2}(1+\epsilon(x))$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\epsilon(x)=0$$

Then
$$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$$
where
$$g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$\int_1^{+\infty}g $ converges by Dirichlet's test.
and

$$h(x)\sim \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2x^{\frac 32}}
$$

$\int_1^{+\infty}h$ converges absolutely since
$$|\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2x^\frac 32}|\le \frac{1}{2x^\frac 32}$$

As a sum of two convergent integrals, your integral is Convergent.

Same for the second.

Comment: Thank you so much! If it is convergent, then can we calculate its value? or specifically for these two it is impossible? Thanks for much again

Comment: @OnAndOff We cannot compute its value.

Comment: Why though? ( I am asking out of curiosity this isn't part of the question)